# Show that relations uRv on a set {u,v} iff simple graf and is symmetrical reflexiv

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I will qoute the question exactally:

> Let G be a an simple graph. Show
>   that the relation R on the set of vertices of G such that uRv, if and
>   only if there is an edge associated {u,v} is symmetric, irreflexive
>   relation on G.

Now, first of all have I understood the question?

I don't know how to show that this is true. My attempts is not worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two properties to prove. I will only give you a brief overview of what you need to do, then it's up to you to try and solve the problem.

---

**Symmetric**.

A relation $R$ is symmetric if $aRb$ implies $bRa$.

Steps:

1. Take any vertices $u,v$ of $G$
2. Assume that $uRv$
3. Something
4. Conclude that $vRu$.

---

**Irreflexive**:

A relation is irreflexive if $aRa$ is not true for any $a$.

Steps:

1. Take any vertex $v$ of graph $G$
2. Write down what $vRv$ would mean.
3. Explain how this is not possible.
4. Conclude $vRv$ is not true.

Comment: Thank you! Now I at know what to solve.